# MPMoviePlayer Troubles

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, ios6

I have three videos on a single viewcontroller, and i am getting this error when I try to play the 3rd:

`2013-02-01 07:44:00.688 LYWAM Tour[1218:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2013-02-01 07:44:00.690 LYWAM Tour[1218:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay`

Here is what I'm using to play the videos:

```
-(void)ThreeVideo8
{
    NSURL *url308 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                            pathForResource:@"LayersofMeaning" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    ThreeVideoSeven =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                        initWithContentURL:url308];

    ThreeVideoEight.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    ThreeVideoEight.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:ThreeVideoEight.view];
    [ThreeVideoEight setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}

-(void) moviePlayBackDidFinish3:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    [ThreeVideoEight.view removeFromSuperview];
    ThreeVideoEight = nil;
}

- (void)moviePlayerWillExitFullscreen3:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    [ThreeVideoEight stop];
    [ThreeVideoEight.view removeFromSuperview];
    ThreeVideoEight = nil;
}
```

But it doesnt load, it just gives me the above errors